# How to set DTR high using a C script in Debian?

Tags: debian, scripting, serial-port

I purchased a HMI running on Debian, Linux. This HMI has a serial port which I'm trying to manipulate. I have a specific problem in my project that can be solved by making the DTR high for a few seconds. I've tried the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
MySerialPort="/dev/ttyS0"
MyLatency="2"
echo "#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
main()
{ int fd; fd = open(\"${MySerialPort}\",O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY );
int RTS_flag; RTS_flag = TIOCM_RTS;
ioctl(fd,TIOCMBIS,&RTS_flag);
sleep (${MyLatency});
ioctl(fd,TIOCMBIC,&RTS_flag);
close(fd); } "
```

However this did not work, it gave me the following errors:

[image]

Does anybody can fix the script I already tried or give me any tips for creating another one?

*UPDATE*

[image]

*UPDATE 2*

Write script:

[image]

Analyze script:

[image]

Sorry its a image, thats because i can not copy from a VM.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you are mixing up shell scripts and C programs. The concept of a "C script" doesn't really exist, and what your script tries to do is simply to print the C source code (i.e. everything from the starting `#include` CPP instruction to the closing bracket of the `main` function) to your console.

The error messages look somewhat as if you tried to compile your shell script.

What instead you must do is to compile your C code and execute the resulting binary.

Comment: Can you check my updated post and review this?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you did with the revised code, and if you keep seeing the same errors? Also, if at all possible please avoid pasting screenshots of code/console I/O, and paste it as verbatim code like you did with your script at the beginning of the question.

Comment: In principle, the revised code looks almost ok and ready to compile; you should still declare the `main` function as `int main(int argv, char *argv[])` and issue a `return 0;` (or any other value indicating success/failure) at the end of the function.

Comment: Hi,

I've changed the code at the "update" post a bit. I changed DTR in to RTS because thats pin 8 on my port. I also used a for loop so it turns on and off every 2 seconds. On my pin 8 I've added a Solid State Relais which needs to switch on/off, however this does not work yet. Do you see any mistakes i made?

Comment: I assume you code compiles correctly, and there are no explicit error messages when running your program - you might still want to add the stereotypical `printf` lines indicating what your program is supposed to be currently doing, just in case. I can of course not say anything about the hardware side, maybe someone on the "electonics" stackexchange can help you there ...

Comment: Hi, I created another script that analyzes the RTS port and print when high or low. However its only high and wont go to low. This means my script is incorrect

Comment: Look at the update 2 topic, this setup does not work.